# RSpec Anonymous mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

RSpec has an [anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) which comes in handy to test the "base" controller of other controllers, please see this example:

#### app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :admin_required

  layout 'admin'

  private

    def admin_required
      render text: 'Unauthorized', status: :unauthorized unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

#### spec/controllers/admin/base_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::BaseController, :type => :controller do
  controller do
    def index
      head :ok
    end
  end

  describe '#index' do
    def do_request
      get :index
    end

    context "as non-admin" do
      before { sign_in create(:user) }

      it 'raises error' do
        do_request
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
        expect(response).not_to be_success
      end
    end

    context "as admin" do
      before { sign_in create(:user, :with_admin) }

      it 'does not raise error' do
        do_request
        expect(response).to be_success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I use a similar structure for my mailers.

My current implementation would need me to add a `test` to `BaseMailer` and add corresponding view for that `test` method.

Is there any way to achieve sort of anonymous mailer testing? something like:

#### app/mailers/base_mailer.rb

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'

  default from:     'Support <support@example.com>',
          reply_to: 'Support <support@example.com>',
end
```

#### spec/mailers/base_mailer_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::BaseController, :type => :mailer do
  mailer do # <= Anonymous mailer!
    def test
      mail
    end
  end

  describe '#welcome' do
    let(:email) { email_to }

    def email_to
      mailer.test # <= Anonymous mailer!
    end

    it { expect(email).to deliver_from 'Support <support@example.com>' }
    it { expect(email).to     reply_to 'Support <support@example.com>' }
  end
end
```

Then I can get rid of having a `test` and `app/views/base_mailer/test.html.erb` file that I'll never used it but just use for testing.

Thanks!

P.S. This mailer testing syntax is from: https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec

Answer (score 3):

Can be achieved, please see [this comment](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1182#issuecomment-57544721):

```
RSpec.describe BaseMailer do
  mailer = Class.new(BaseMailer) do
    def a_sample_email
      # We need a body to not render views
      mail(body: '')
    end
  end

  it 'has the default "from" address' do
    email = mailer.a_sample_email
    expect(email.from).to eq 'Support <support@example.com>'
  end
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1182